# High TTFB time using Open Server

Tags: wordpress, localserver

Developing WP website using Open Server. When opening pages it loads few seconds before it starts opening. Opened waterfall and see that there is high TTFB.

[image]

I understand, that here is problem in Open Server settings. The server address is `127.0.0.1` and such module settings:

[image]

Please someone give a hint where to look for solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in active IPv6 in my Windows 10. In Open Server console after calling `ping localhost` was `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`.
Solved the problem by disabling IPv6 in Registry Editor.
[Here is a short tutorial.](https://tweaks.com/windows/40099/how-to-properly-disable-ipv6/)
Good luck!